# How to properly concatenate string literal to string variable and reassign to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a string literal to a string variable and reassign this value to the same variable.

I've tried the `+=` operator and something like

```py
string = string + "another string"
```

but that doesn't work.

Here is my code.

```py
userWord = input("Enter a word: ").upper()

# Prompt the user to enter a word and assign it to the userWord variable


for letter in userWord:
    # Loops through userWord and concatenates consonants to wordWithoutVowels and skips vowels
    if letter == "A" or letter == "E" or letter == "I" or letter == "O" or letter == "U":
        continue
    wordWithoutVowels += userWord # NameError: name "wordWithoutVowels" is not defined

print(wordWithoutVowels)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I think you intended to do `wordWithoutVowels += letter`, not the entire `userWord`. Secondly, that expression is the same as `wordWithoutVowels = wordWithoutVowels + userWord`, which means that `wordWithoutVowels` needs to be defined before it.

Simply add the following before the `for` loop

```
wordWithoutVowels = ''
```

---

**Edit:**

As @DeveshKumarSingh mentioned, you can further improve the loop by using the following `if` condition instead of using `continue`

```
if letter not in ['A','E','I','O','U']:
    wordWithoutVowels += letter
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add `wordWithoutVowels = ""` and didn't mean to concatenate the entire userWord but rerunning it throws the same error.

Comment: Could you update the code in your question? Because it works fine for me

Comment: You are right. I have updated my question (the code runs now)

Comment: I meant update if it was not working. Your question now has the correct code with an error that doesn't happen. Please revert that edit, and mark this answer as accepted since it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Some issues with your code

- You are not initializing `wordWithoutVowels` before the for loop. You need to do that with `wordWithoutVowels = ''`
- You can use the `in` operator to check if the letter is not present in vowels, and then only update the result string

The updated code will then be

```
userWord = input("Enter a word: ").upper()

#Initialize wordWithoutVowels
wordWithoutVowels = ''
for letter in userWord:
    #If letter does not fall in vowels, append that letter
    if letter not in ['A','E','I','O','U']:
        wordWithoutVowels += letter 

print(wordWithoutVowels)
```

The output will be

```
Enter a word: hello world
HLL WRLD
```